# Parse: Duplicate records for the a single saveInBackground Call

Tags: java, android, parse-platform

I have a single incident where a complete duplicate of a entry was made into the database (the same user comment appeared twice). They had different object IDs but were otherwise the exact same. It was slower than usual to finish the posting and only happened once out of dozens of comments, so I want to say it was a Parse issue during the saveInBackground call. Even so, I expect a service like Parse to be a little more robust. As my first time working with Android though, I also can't be sure nothing is wrong on my end. Any help? Also just any criticisms? This is the method called when the user hits a comment submission button:

```
private void submitComment() {

    String text = commentText.getText().toString().trim();
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    String ID = intent.getStringExtra("imageID");
    String parentID = intent.getStringExtra("parent");

    // Set up a progress dialog
    final ProgressDialog loadingDialog = new ProgressDialog(CommentSubmitActivity.this);
    loadingDialog.setMessage(getString(R.string.publishing_comment));
    loadingDialog.show();

    Comment comment = new Comment();
    comment.setText(text);
    comment.setUser((ParseUser.getCurrentUser()));
    if (ID.equals("@child")) {
        comment.setParent(parentID);
        comment.setImage("@child");

        ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery.getQuery("Comment");
        query.getInBackground(parentID, new GetCallback<ParseObject>() {
            public void done(ParseObject parentComment, ParseException e) {
                if (e == null) {
                    int numChild = parentComment.getInt("numChild");
                    parentComment.put("numChild", ++numChild);
                    parentComment.saveInBackground();
                } else {
                    Log.d("numChild: ", "error");
                }
            }
        });
    } else {
        comment.setImage(ID);
        comment.put("numChild", 0);

        ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery.getQuery("ImageUpload");
        query.getInBackground(ID, new GetCallback<ParseObject>() {
            public void done(ParseObject image, ParseException e) {
                if (e == null) {
                    int numComments = image.getInt("numComments");
                    image.put("numComments", ++numComments);
                    image.saveInBackground();
                } else {
                    Log.d("numComments: ", "error");
                }
            }
        });

    }

    comment.saveInBackground(new SaveCallback() {
        @Override
        public void done(ParseException e) {
            if (e == null) {
                loadingDialog.dismiss();
                finish();
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I encountered similar problem like yours.
I created an app where user can create account and add photo to it and list of objects (friends in my case).
Once when I was testing it user was created twice.
I went through my code and my my suspicions are connected with async calls.
I see that you use asynchronous parse api in you application so no fragment of code is waiting for response and blocking the rest of operations.
You cannot control when parse server will response.
What I did I just put all synchronous requests in my custom async code (AsyncTask in Android).

Hope that my answer somehow meeets your expectations.